How to solve second order partial differential equation with two variables?
Can someone help me solve following differential equation:
$$
\lambda_{xx}\lambda_{tt} - \lambda_{tx}\lambda_{tx} = 0
$$
Just to be clear $\lambda = \lambda\left(t, x\right)$ is scalar function of two variables. $\lambda_{xx}$, $\lambda_{tt}$ and $\lambda_{tx}$ are second order partial derivatives.
Thank you,

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

A good suggestion from @Doug. So maybe with
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{xx} & \lambda_{xt} \
\lambda_{tx} & \lambda_{tt}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
does this suggest $\lambda_{xx} = a\lambda_{xt}$ and $\lambda_{tx} = a\lambda_{tt}$? If so, then $\lambda_{xx} = a^2\lambda_{tt}$ where, at this point, $a$ is arbitrary.

Please specify the initial and the boundary conditions. Without them, your question is too vague.

This is the homogeneous Monge-Ampere equation. Taking the Euler transformation $x=u_{\xi},\ t=\eta,\ \lambda=x\xi-u$ and taking a few derivatives yields
\begin{align}
&\lambda_x=\xi,\quad \lambda_t=-u_{\eta},\quad \text{and}\\
&\lambda_{xx}=\frac{1}{u_{\xi\xi}}, \quad \lambda_{tx}=-\frac{u_{\xi\eta}}{u_{\xi\xi}},\quad \lambda_{tt}=\frac{u_{\xi\eta}^2-u_{\xi\xi}u_{\eta\eta}}{u_{\xi\xi}}.
\end{align}
Upon substitution we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{\eta\eta}}{u_{\xi\xi}}=0.
\end{align}
So then our solution is
\begin{align}
u=-\varphi(\xi)\eta-\psi(\xi),
\end{align}
for functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$. Using $\lambda=\xi u_{\xi}-u$ and $x=u_{\xi}$ we find the parametric solution
\begin{align}
\lambda=\xi x+\varphi(\xi)t+\psi(\xi),\\
x+\varphi'(\xi)t+\psi(\xi)=0.
\end{align}

Hint.
Making $\lambda(t,x) = T(t)X(x)$ we have
$$
T X''T''X=(T')^2(X')^2\Rightarrow \frac {TT''}{(T')^2}\frac{XX''}{(X')^2}=1
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\cases{
\frac {TT''}{(T')^2}=\mu\Rightarrow \frac{T''}{T'} = \mu\frac{T'}{T}\\
\frac{XX''}{(X')^2}=\frac{1}{\mu}\Rightarrow \frac{X''}{X'} = \frac{1}{\mu}\frac{X'}{X}
}
$$
so $\lambda(t,x) = T(t)X(x) = \sum_k((1-\mu_k) (c_1 t+c_{1,2})){}^{\frac{1}{1-\mu_k }} \left(\frac{(\mu_k -1) (c_2
   x+c_{2,2})}{\mu_k }\right){}^{\frac{\mu_k }{\mu_k -1}}$
A MATHEMATICA script to verify the solution:
solT     = DSolve[T'[t] == c1 T[t]^mu, T, t][[1]];
solX     = DSolve[X'[x] == c2 X[x]^(1/mu), X, x][[1]];
lambda1  = X[x] T[t] /. solT /. solX;
lambda2  = lambda1 /. {mu -> mu2};
lambda12 = lambda1 + lambda2;
D[lambda12, x, x] D[lambda12, t, t] - D[lambda12, x, t]^2 // FullSimplify;


The PDE is nonlinear. Are you sure the sum of solutions also is a solution?

Please. See MATHEMATICA script attached.

A rural reader's comment on OP probably allows for easier characterization of solutions as solutions of any wave equation or diagonal anisotropic elliptic equation. It's not obvious to me that this solution can reproduce, e.g., D'Alembert's solution
